# How can I format strings for use as structure field names in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, field, matlab-struct

I want to remove hyphens (`-`), slashes (`/`) and white space () from a string `name(i)` so that I can use it as a structure field name.

This is the ugly way I am currently doing it using the function [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html):

```
cell2mat(strrep(strrep(strrep(name(i), '-',''),'/',''),' ', ''))
```

I have also tried other variations, such as:

```
strrep(name(i),{'-','/'},{'',''});
strrep(name(i),['-','/'],['','']);
```

What is a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Note:* I'm guessing your variable `name` is a cell array of strings, in which case you will want to use `{}` (i.e. [*content* indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-108)) instead of `()` (i.e. [*cell* indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-108)) to get the strings from it...

As with many problems in MATLAB, there are a number of different ways you can solve this...

**Option 1:** You could use the function [REGEXPREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html). The following removes hyphens, forward slashes, and whitespace:

```
newName = regexprep(name{i},'[-/\s]','');
```

The benefit here is that the `\s` will match and replace *all* whitespace characters, which includes a normal space (ASCII code 32) as well as tabs, newlines, etc..

If you want to be safe and remove *every* character that is not valid in a [MATLAB variable/field name](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isvarname.html), you can simplify the above to this:

```
newName = regexprep(name{i},'\W','');
```

**Option 2:** If you don't need to worry about removing anything other than the 3 characters you listed, you could use the function [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) like so:

```
newName = name{i};
newName(ismember(newName,'-/ ')) = [];
```

**Option 3:** If you want to just keep everything that is an alphanumeric character and dump the rest (hyphens, whitespace, underscores, etc.), you could use the function [ISSTRPROP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isstrprop.html):

```
newName = name{i};
newName = newName(isstrprop(newName,'alphanum'));
```

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.  :)  Seriously -nice.

Comment: I was already using regexp and just wanted to know what are legal characters, so no new problems for me... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use the built in function genvarname.  It will make the name look uglier, but its guaranteed to be a valid name AND it will retain you original uniqueness.

If you just want to remove specific characters, you can use regexprep:

```
regexprep('foo- /foo- /foo', '[- \/]', '')
```

Comment: +1: `genvarname` is the correct solution to the overall problem.  Regular expressions, however, are a heavyweight solution to a simple problem.

Comment: GENVARNAME is interesting, but it only removes the spaces. It replaces the other characters by their hex representations, which makes for a hideous name to use for a structure field.

Comment: As I said above, it will make the name look ugly, but it guarantees your name is valid and retains your original uniqueness.  If you want to manually replace / delete chars, you have to be careful to 1) remove all invalid chars 2) not destroy your original uniqueness.

Comment: hang: The "not destroying uniqueness" point is a good one, although it would be kind of odd if the hyphens, slashes, and such were the *only* things making the strings unique.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are just arrays, so you could do something like:

```
name(name == '-' | name == '/' | name = ' ') = [];
```

With respect to your overall goal, there are many more characters that aren't valid in a struct name.  You're bet off defining a set of *allowable* characters, and eliminating everything that isn't in that set.

e.g.:

```
function i = isAllowed(str)

i = (str >= '0' & str <= '9') ...
  | (str >= 'a' & str <= 'z') ...
  | (str >= 'A' & str <= 'Z');


...

name(~isAllowed(name)) = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
name = 'some/path/file-name ext';    %# sample string
blacklist = {'-' '/' ' '};           %# list of character not allowed

idx = cell2mat( cellfun(@(c)strfind(name,c), blacklist, 'UniformOutput',false) );
name(idx) = '_';                    %# you can remove/replace those locations

>> name
 name =
 some_path_file_name_ext
```